# Docker unable to login to Nexus docker registry (hosted)

Tags: docker, nexus3

I have configured the Docker registry (hosted) in the nexus server https://nexus.mycompany.com and have enabled the HTTP connector port on 8083.

I am unable to push images to the Docker repository from my Jenkins server.

I have added nexus server in insecure registries in Jenkins server .x

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
  "insecure-registries": [
     "nexus.mycompany.com:8082",
     "nexus.mycompany.com:8083"
  ]
}
```

when i run

docker login -u admin -p xxxxx nexus.mycompany.com:8083

I get the below error

**WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get http://nexus.mycompany.com:8083/v2/: dial tcp xxx.xx.0.xx:8083: connect: no route to host**

I have configured SSL vis apache httpd below is my conf.d file in Jenkins server. Am I missing something in proxy settings?

---

````
<VirtualHost xxx.xx.x.xx:80>

ServerName jenkins.mycompany.com
ProxyRequests Off
RewriteEngine on

ProxyPass /jenkins http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins  http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/jenkins


ProxyPreserveHost On

LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/jenkins-error.log
CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/jenkins-access.log combined

#Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost xxx.xx.x.xx:443>
ServerName jenkins.mycompany.com

TimeOut 900

<Directory />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf.d/.ssl/mycompany.com.key
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf.d/.ssl/mycompany.com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/.ssl/mycompany.comca.crt

ProxyRequests Off
RewriteEngine on

ProxyPass /jenkins  http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins  http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/jenkins


ProxyPreserveHost On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/jenkins-ssl-error.log
CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/jenkins-ssl-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>```



I can connect to the Docker registry from the nexus server.
Jenkins server ports 
Below are my port settings on the Jenkins server.

```Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      15505/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      15505/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      15505/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
.```
````

Comment: It seems that your jenkins server cannot contact your nexus. What happens when you `curl` nexus from jenkins ? `curl nexus.mycompany.com:8083`

Comment: ``curl -v nexus.mycompany.com ** Connection #0 to host nexus.mycompany.com left intact**``  I am able to get response but i am unable to curl with port number. ```curl -v nexus.mycompany.com:8083. About to connect() to nexus.mycompany.com port 8083 (#0) * Trying xxx.xx.x.86... * No route to host * Failed connect to nexus.mycompany.com:8083; No route to host * Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed connect to nexus.mycompany.com:8083; No route to host –```

Comment: Well then this means that your nexus is not exposed on the `8083` port. What happens when you try that url on your browser ?

Comment: yeah but repository url cannot be accessed with the port number  from the browser i believe . i can access the repository from the browser but while pushing artifacts/images we use portnumber and  it is not available in browser. also i checked for the port number in nexus server and can see 8083 is listening .  netstat -lntu |grep -i 8083 **tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -**

Comment: Then does it work if you try that config from your computer and not the jenkins server ?

Comment: i dont have docker in my computer i  will try to install or i will try from another linux server. also if it matters I want to mention that i  was able to successfully push images from the linux server where nexus is installed to  same repo with port  8083.

Answer (score 1):

It was simple port Issue .though the port 8083 was listening it was not accepting traffic.

I edited the iptables added 8083 to accept inbound traffic and i was able to login .